# getting the body.text content of a Word document does not return the lists bullets/numbers

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

Using the Word JavaScript APIs, I get the body text using

```
var body = context.document.body;
context.load(body, 'text');

return context.sync().then(function () {
     var myDocBody = body.text;
};
```

However this does not return bullets within an unordered list, or numbers within an ordered list.

What is the best way to get these within the plain text?

Also is there a way to get tables and formatting? At the moment the tables are returned in the plain text but there is no way to know that they were tables by just looking at the text.

Comment: Have you tried the `getHtml()` method? This returns HTML which may be easier for you to parse, particularly when it comes to tables, formatting, lists, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code and I can get the text from the lists.
Not sure if you are aware of this but there is a range.lists and range.tables that you can get access to the lists and tables in the document.

can you please share in what platform you are experiencing this issue? (i.e. Win32, Online, Mac, etc) and please also share build numbers.

Comment: I get the text but not the bullet symbol of the unordered lists or the item number of ordered lists.

Comment: That is because the bullet/number comes from the formatting applied to the text, not part of the text itself. It is similar to how **bold** text is returned as raw text.